# How can I make the image of a bounding box invisible in java

Tags: java, android, swing, java-me

I want to hard code an oval image and use it as a sprite in a pong ball example I've been following online, on a j2me platform.

I'm able to draw the oval image, but I want to make the bounding box of the image invisible or the same as the canvas' colour?

Any Ideas???

Comment: Post what you have so far. Otherwise it is just to vague a question.

Comment: for example, one solution would be to make the background colour of the canvas the same as the colour of the bounding box.

Comment: this is the code for the image: im = Image.createImage(30,30); Graphics graphics = im.getGraphics; graphics.setColor(0,0,0) ;//for black... graphics.fillRoundRect(x, y, a, b, s, t); Now when I run the app there are white corners around the cirlcle, can I change those colours to another colour? Or should I use the work around I thought of above..? I'm just curios really?

Comment: I guess the real question is what would be the member_function_name to use with the calling_object (graphics - above) in order to change the colour of the image's bounding box, that is, if there is one... And how could I use it or at least where can I learn how to use it???

Comment: P.S. The work-around works but it sucks...

Comment: Please don't put code in comments. Put code in the question.
Also: You can just call `fillRoundRect(x,y,a,b,s,t)` on your `Canvas` graphics object, instead of creating a new image. That'll solve your problem.

Comment: sorry about putting the code in the question... the p.c. I'm working on is too far from the modem.. if I draw on the canvas will the image run as a sprite(sorry if I didn't phrase that correctly)? let me find out real quickly!!! but im just curious if anyone knows before hand. thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could create oval image with pixels outside the oval transparent using createRGBImage(...) where you supply array of ARGB values for every pixel in the image.